# Сonfigure testBed for Pipe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, pipe, karma-jasmine

Colleagues, can anyone tell me, I'm trying to configure testBed for the pipe, and it works only if I drop the pipe itself into the providers, which I will test.
I can't get around this in any way, can you tell me what's the matter?
Second question: in addition to the transform method, I have a private method in the pipe, how can I test it ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to do it [this](https://angular.io/guide/testing-pipes#testing-the-titlecasepipe) way.

But having it as a provider is fine and you're grabbing a handle on it.

To test the private method, you can make the environment proper so it traverses the private method.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'xyz', pure: true })
export class SdDateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
   value: number;
   constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe, private configService: ConfigService) {}

   transform(value: string): string {
     if (value.includes('a')) {
       this.setValue(1);
     } else {
       this.setValue(2);
     }
   }

   private setValue(num: number) {
     this.value = num;
   }
}
```

```
it("should set value to 1 if the string has a", () => {
  pipe.transform('abc');
  expect(pipe.value).toBe(1);
});

it("should set value to 2 if the string does not have an a", () => {
  pipe.transform('xyz');
  expect(pipe.value).toBe(2);
});
```

So at the end of the day, see what you get from the private method and assert it does what it should have done.

Answer (score 0):

You can instanciate using let pipe = new SdDateFormatPipe()  if it has no depedencies injection.

About the private method, it is probably being called inside a public method, so to cover it on your tests, the correct and recommended way to do it would be making a test case in which it will call the private method.